# Query JSON With Unknown Structure

Tags: c#, json

We are trying to write a way to consume a JSON feed from a third party but unfortunately it's not well written, there appears to be no rules on what is sometimes there or not and also the structure changes depending on the key, I have no way of changing this we have to work with what we have.  We know what we want based on certain keys but we are struggling to find them as the nested structure changes.

Is it possible to flatten the JSON down to a single List> that we can query and the key would be the fully qualified name including parents so the following JSON:

```
{
  "employees": [
     { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
     { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
     { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
     ]
}
```

Would become a list with keys like:

```
"employees.firstName" and a value of "John".
```

I think if we could get to this we could query the data for what we want, we have been trying to use dynamic objects but as I said the JSON changes and properties are missing sometimes and it's proving impossible to handle all scenarios.

Comment: you can parse any json in `dictionary` so you can `employees["firstName"]` is `"John"`

Comment: This was a very simplified solution, unfortunately the JSON we are getting is very nested sometimes 10 layers deep and as I said we don't always know what it will look like but the property names are set, so if we could get a string with a key like "level1.level2.level3.level4.level5.firstName" then we could query for "firstName".

Comment: you can see about [JObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and JSON.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know reliably the structure of a JSON but you are sure about property name ex "firstName". You can use the JSON.NET JObject and recursively loop through it and check if the property you are looking for exists in the current JToken.

The code should look something Like that, note the code I didn't compile it can have some typing mistakes:

```
private  List<string> LoadFirstNames(string json)
{
   JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
   List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
   foreach(var token in o.GetPropertyValues())
   {
    FindFirstName(token, firstNames);
   }

   return firstNames;
}

private void FindFirstName(JToken currentProperty, List<string> firstNamesCollection)
{
   if(currentProperty == null)
   {
     return;
   }

   if(currentProperty["firstName"] != null)
   {
       firstNamesCollection.Add(currentProperty["firstName"]);
   }

   foreach(var token into currentProperty.Values())
   {
     FindFirstName(token , firstNamesCollection);
   }

}
```

Comment: This got me to the right answer, although I was still getting exceptions when checking if a value was null and it didn't exist with a dynamic object so had to create a method to wrap a try...catch and return false if there was an error.